# Thread 1: "-[_UIDatePickerIOSCompactView setHighlightsToday:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker, ios14

I'm getting crash reports from iOS 14, from using setHighlightsToday with the UIDatePicker.

```
Thread 1: "-[_UIDatePickerIOSCompactView setHighlightsToday:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"
```

I can't see a fix for highlighting today?

I know I need to also check for the selector being available.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/pull/249/commits/e715cce1f8bef3cdb693b3ab5e88f4e8cbc46ec2

Comment: Thanks,  but I was hoping there was a new way of doing this.

Comment: I believe this only works for `UIDatePickerStyleWheels`, otherwise you get the crash, even on iOS 14.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this.

```
 if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
       datepicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
       datepicker.setValue(false, forKeyPath: "highlightsToday")
  }
```